# Apple Music API - How to get user identifier?

Tags: api, apple-music, apple-musickit

I am trying to retrieve the user's information after getting the Music Token from the Apple Music API. It seems that the /me endpoint is not available for queries other than the storefront (https://api.music.apple.com/v1/me/storefront).

Problem is, I need to identify each user with a unique ID, so I need to retrieve any good information to do that (for example, the email address could be a good starting point).

From the Apple Music API developer page, I can't find any endpoint to do so. Is there something I am missing?

Thank you :)

Comment: Super frustrating! Did you ever found a workaround for this? I placed a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67649023/use-token-from-sign-in-with-apple-to-query-apple-music-api

Answer (score 2):

No, you're not missing anything. It's really frustrating that you can't get any user data from the api, because it probably means you'll have to also provide another sign-on method like Google or email/password to get information. Apple has just released its own SSO [here](https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/get-started/), but I think the user would still have to authenticate that and MusicKit.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one who finds this extremely frustrating. They should either provide a unique user id, or add an additional scope to their "Sign in with Apple" service for getting music. I have an app that authenticates with Apple and then we need to pop up another login window for their music access. Either unintentionally bad UX or intentional access "stone walling". Maybe someday they'll look at how the rest of the world does some things instead of trying to always reinvent them.